# Tomcat Apache 8.0 Server

Tags: java, apache, tomcat

I had my tomcat working for my environment from eclipse working the other day. Today It is not even running the basic tomcat from the command line. Here is what I am getting

```
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.397 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.45
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.399 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 26 2017 20:06:07 UTC
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.399 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server number:         8.0.45.0
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.399 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.399 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.400 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.400 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_141\jre
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.400 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_141-b15
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.400 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.400 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.45
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.400 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.45
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.401 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.45\conf\logging.properties
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.401 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.401 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.401 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.401 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.45\endorsed
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.401 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.45
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.402 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.45
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.403 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.45\temp
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.404 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.2.12 using APR version 1.5.2.
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.405 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
04-Aug-2017 10:08:41.927 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.initializeSSL OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017)
04-Aug-2017 10:08:42.034 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
04-Aug-2017 10:08:42.044 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
04-Aug-2017 10:08:42.045 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 980 ms
04-Aug-2017 10:08:42.069 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service Catalina
04-Aug-2017 10:08:42.070 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.45
04-Aug-2017 10:08:42.079 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deploying web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.45\webapps\ROOT
04-Aug-2017 10:08:42.704 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
04-Aug-2017 10:08:42.805 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory C:\apache-tomcat-8.0.45\webapps\ROOT has finished in 725 ms
04-Aug-2017 10:08:42.809 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
04-Aug-2017 10:08:42.821 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
04-Aug-2017 10:08:42.828 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in 782 ms
```

I am getting a 404 error. I am using localhost8080

thanks for the help.

Comment: That's not an error. It's a success message. Try using `localhost:8080`. (Colon before the port.)

Comment: It starts up success, yes. But when I visit localhost:8080 like normal

HTTP Status 404 - /

type Status report

message /

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.45

Comment: That just means you don't have anything deployed to webapps/ROOT.

Comment: Thank you for your time.